# PHP with MongoDB what is better selectCollection or getDB

Tags: php, mongodb, optimization, query-optimization

We are using MongoDB for our PHP application. For these two methods. Which is better performance wise.

```
$this->forum = MongoAutonymity::getInstance()->getDB()->selectCollection('forum');
$this->forum_similar_forums = MongoAutonymity::getInstance()->getDB()->forum_similar_forums;
```

Here are GetDB and GetInstance function code.

```
public function getDB()
{
        return $this->database;
}

public static function getInstance()
{
        if (is_null(self::$instance))
        {
            self::$instance = new MongoAutonymity();
        }
        return self::$instance;
}
```

With large data (not much large though just around 30,000 records), our application speed have reduced to 30 seconds for 1 page. I want to make it not more than 10 seconds. I guess issue is with data load. So, any help with it?

Thanks

Comment: both selectcollection and getdb are the exact same function, one is just uses a magic function and the other doesn't, the speed will be in the magics which will be like 0.000000000000000000000000004ms

Answer (score 0):

This is not your performance bottleneck.

If your script is really taking 30 seconds for one page then your queries are completely unindexed. You should run ->explain() on the queries you are running to understand what is going on and create your indexes based on your query pattern.

See http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/applications/indexes/